# WebKit View not opening certain URLs

Tags: ios, xcode, hyperlink, wkwebview

I want the webkit view to display my domain webpage but it won't work. It works for regular known websites but not for my own domain. I am using the code below. Also I added this to the pList file but no joy. Thanks in advance.

pList
NSAppTransportSecurity
NSAllowsArbitraryLoads

Code:

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, WKNavigationDelegate {

    var webView: WKWebView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        webView = WKWebView()
        webView.navigationDelegate = self
        view = webView

        webView.frame = view.bounds
        webView.navigationDelegate = self

        let url = URL(string: "https://www.MYDOMAIN.co.uk")!
        webView.load(URLRequest(url: url))
        webView.allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures = true

    }
}
```

Comment: can you please add `webview` `delegates` and check what error you are getting?

Comment: can you please share your actual domain link so, I can help you with it.

Answer (score 0):

Try for this

```
class YourCalssviewController : UIViewController ,WKNavigationDelegate ,WKUIDelegate{ }
```

Write in viewDidLoad()

```
    let url = NSURL(string: "https://www.MYDOMAIN.co.uk")
    let request = NSURLRequest(url: url! as URL)
    self.webView.load(request as URLRequest)
```

Answer (score 0):

your code is working fine, the problem here with the URL itself, if you tried an other URL like *"https://www.youtube.com/"*  it will work fine